# d3 barchart - how to select bar by hovering above it in empty space?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

Take this site for example

https://codepen.io/dwilbank68/pen/PNVyyo?editors=0010

I want to be able to drag the mouse in the empty space above the bars, and still trigger the mouseover callback.

Is there an easy way to do this?

The best way I can think of right now (a beginner), is to stack white bars (effectively invisible) on top of the gray bars, and have them trigger the mouseover callback.

Hoping there's a better way though. My way sounds like a doubling of work.

Here's the code, only because the site says I have to paste it in.

```
var data = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json'

var m = {t: 20, r: 20, b: 60, l: 60},
    width = 960 - m.l - m.r,
    height = 500 - m.t - m.b;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
              .attr("width", width + m.l + m.r)
              .attr("height", height + m.t + m.b)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" +m.l+ "," +m.t+ ")");

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
                      .range([0,width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                      .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(xScale)
                  .orient("bottom")
                  .ticks(20)
                  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(yScale)
                  .orient("left")

// Template for Tooltip

var tooltip = d3.select('body')
            .append('div')
              .style({
                  'position':'absolute',
                  // 'text-align':'center',
                  'width':'240px',
                  'height':'2.5em',
                  'font':'1.5em sans-serif',
                  'color':'black',
                  'background':'white',
                  'border-radius':'8px',
                  'border':'double 3px darkgray',
                  'opacity':0
              });

d3.json(data, callback);

// FUNCTIONS

function callback (error, data) {

    if (error) throw error;

    var parseTime = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    var dataArr = data['data'].map(function(d){
        return {
            'date': parseTime(d[0]),
            'billionDollars' : d[1]
        }
    })

    var barWidth = Math.ceil(width / dataArr.length);

    var dateMin = d3.min(_.map(dataArr,'date'));
    var dateMax = d3.max(_.map(dataArr,'date'));

    var desc = data.description;

     // console.log(JSON.stringify( dataArr, null, '  '));
    xScale.domain([dateMin, dateMax]);

    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataArr, (d)=> d.billionDollars)]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
            .text("Gross Domestic Product, USA")
            .attr({
              'class': 'label',
              "transform": "rotate(-90)",
              "y": 6,
              "dy": ".71em"
            })
            .style("text-anchor", "end");

    svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(dataArr)
        .enter()
          .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('width', barWidth )
            .attr('x', (d)=> xScale(d.date) )
            .attr('y', (d)=> yScale(d.billionDollars) )
            .attr('height', (d)=> height - yScale(d.billionDollars) )
            .attr('fill', 'gray');

    d3.selectAll('.bar')
      .on('mouseover', mouseover)
      .on('mouseout', mouseout);

    d3.select('.description')
      .text(desc)



};
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y %b")

var formatCurrency = d3.format("$,.2f");

function mouseover(d){

    tooltip.html('<span class="tooltip-currency">'+
                      formatCurrency(d.billionDollars)+ ' Billion' +
                 '</span>'+
                 '<br/>'+
                 '<span class="tooltip-date">'+
                    formatDate(d.date) +
                 '</span>')
            .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 9) +'px')
            .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 43) +'px');

    tooltip.transition()
            .style('opacity', 1);
}

function mouseout(){
    tooltip.transition()
            .style('opacity', 1e-6);
}
```

Comment: Your way is OK, a common solution, you don't need a voronoi here. It'd be even more simple if you create the transparent bars going from bottom to top, over the regular bars (to do this, just append the transparent ones later in the code) and let these transparent bars deal with all the mouseover.

Comment: Never thought to mess with transparent bars like that but that is indeed the easiest way! Thanks